# Source impedance influence on DC/DC converter input impedance measurement

Tags: dc-dc-converter, impedance, measurement, vna

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqUvMl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have been tasked to verify the input impedance of a medium powered DC/DC converter (<1kW), and no experienced colleagues to consult on the matter. I have quite a good description of the required test setup, including the choice of isolation transformer for coupling in the AC pertubation, current and voltage probes. I'm intentionally holding back on the details here for anonymity reasons, so apologies for that.

It is clear, that I need to exercise caution not to saturate the transformer core at low frequencies and keep a close eye on the primary and secondary levels.

What is missing, however, is the description of the power source, and this is where the uncertainty starts. Looking at the setup, I assume there's no way the source output capacitance isn't going to influence the measurements of the input impedance at the input of the converter.

The question is what calibration method to use for the VNA in order to compensate for the excess capacitance of the source. The VNA/FRA available is generic, and will dump the voltage magnitude/phase it sees at its inputs, and is not guiding the user through any calibration procedure.

How, oh wise masters, would you proceed in order to get a trustworthy measurement?

Comment: You can have a look at this [paper](http://www.deltartp.com/dpel/dpelconferencepapers/33.3_10275.pdf) published by Delta Electronics folks from Raleigh (NC) where they explore different approaches. You certainly should not insert a transformer in series with the input line but resort to a solid-state injector with a series-pass MOSFET for instance. For more about the interaction between the filter and the dc-dc converter, have a look at my [APEC 2017](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202017.pdf).

Comment: You don't need to care about the capacitance cos' you measure V and I at the converter directly. This [AN](https://www.omicron-lab.com/fileadmin/assets/Bode_100/ApplicationNotes/Input_Impedance/AppNote_InputImpedance_V1.0.pdf) from Omicron might be worth reading too. I would recommend you to simulate the \$Z_{in}\$ of your converter using SIMPLIS for instance (you use one my free 80+ ready-made [template](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf)). Having an idea of what you should expect from the bench is good for engineering judgement.

Comment: What an honour to get answers from Mr. Kint himself! I have two of your books on my bookshelf next to the one of Erickson and Maksimovic. But coming back to your comments, the use of this specific transformer (Solar) is prescribed in the measurement requirements. About the source capacitance, I did find the Delta paper, some Omicron and Venable ANs, which all ignore the influence of the source impedance. I can't quite get it into my head. The only thing which is different for the source and load measurements is the placement of the voltage probe behind or in front of the transformer secondary.

Comment: I suppose another way to look at it is, that since it is a one-port, only the impedance of the port will relate the voltage and current phasors measured directly across it. A bit like the current and voltage relationship of a simple resistor won't change, even if a more complex circuit is connected to it.

Comment: One other concern, which comes to mind is the closed loop control of the source power supply. I wonder how its regulation loop will cope with an AC interference from the transformer. I suppose this is one of the reasons people keep telling you to closely monitor the secondary current and voltage with a finger on the "output on/off" button.

Comment: Regarding the \$Z_{in}\$, the input EMI filter has been modeled in spice with the converter represented by a resistive load, as the converter itself is a black box commercial one. The EMI filter is grossly overdimensioned, though, which ought to eclipse the converter impedance completely.

Comment: Oui, because you measure the input variables at the dc-dc input port, in principle, you do not care about the source impedance I guess. Also, I don't foresee an interaction with the dc source as you have to limit the perturbation level anyway to maintain a small-signal condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short follow-up to share how the measurement went. Verbal Kint was right, it was just that simple. One learning that I did have, was that using a DMM for an RMS voltage measurement on the injection side is not a good idea above 1 kHz, as this is where the "True RMS" apparently ends. No harm done, but certainly educational. Better to use an oscilloscope in the future.